# Stat struct "Field 'st_size' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, eclipse-cdt

I'm having problems with st_size of stat struct in a simple program for Raspberry Pi. 
I write the code in Eclipse C/C++ IDE (CDT) with a Macbook, and then compile it in the Raspberry Pi. I didn't have problems until I started using fstat and stat structure.

I test this code in Raspberry Pi and it work fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {


        FILE *pFile;
        struct stat buf;

        pFile = fopen("File.bin","rb");

        if ( pFile != 0  ) {

                fstat(fileno(pFile), &buf);
                printf("File size: %d\n", buf.st_size);
                //printf("File size: %d\n", buf.stat);

                fclose(pFile);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I tried to use buf.st_size the Eclipse throws Field 'st_size' could not be resolve. Instead, the Eclipse autocomplete with '.stat' like the commented line (buf.stat). 
So far, I added in "C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes" the path where I copied the includes "stat.h" obtained from the "Raspberry Pi". 
I can't make "Field 'st_size' could not be resolve" problem go away. 
Any suggestion would be appreciate!

Thank you for your time

Comment: `arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/stat.h` - that's a strange include. Just `#include <sys/stat.h>`. `I write the code in Eclipse C/C++ IDE (CDT) with a Macbook, and then compile it in the Raspberry Pi` - so you need to accept the fact, that eclipse does not know what raspberry pi includes are and can't index them. You can copy them all `/usr/include` to your PC and add include path to eclipse, but it feels crude.

Comment: ...also, who throws what errors and when? Please be precise. Also, trim your code to the necessary [mcve]. Further readings: [tour] and [ask]. Please take the time to study those.

Comment: I don't know why I can not mark the question as answered. (The check mark doesn't appear below the down arrow). 
Thanks to Kamil Cuk answer, I was able to fix the Eclipse IDE problem. I changed the #include <arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/stat.h> for #include <sys/stat.h>.

Comment: Ulrich Eckhardt sorry if I didn't express very well. 
Who: The Eclipse IDE mark that error in the editor window where I wrote the code. 
When: The error appear when I wrote "buf.st_size". 
I will have in mind your suggestion.

Comment: You can answer your own question, and mark the answer as accepted. (Only answers can be marked as accepted, not questions.)